# Correct Xpath to output title in this example?

Tags: xpath

I'm playing around with this piece of code, trying to figure out how to extract title information via XPATH, and since it's on an internal network, I don't have access to something like Firepath.

```
<div style="float:left">
<table border="0">
<tbody>
   <tr width="100%">
      <td valign="top">Code that does not matter</td>
      <td colspan="2">
          <span class="textinfo">
          <a href="http.....">
             <b> HI!  I am the TITLE!</b>
          </a>
          </span>
      </td>
   </tr>
   <tr></tr>
   <tr></tr>
   <tr width="100%">
      <td valign="top">Code that does not matter</td>
      <td colspan="2">
          <span class="textinfo">
          <a href="http.....">
             <b> HI!  Here is another TITLE!</b>
          </a>
          </span>
      </td>
    </tr>
   </tbody>
  </table>
  </div>
```

It goes on like this for a while.  Basically there are 10 results and I'm trying to figure out how to get all titles.  Any ideas?  Did I provide enough info?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

What you have in the sample isn't a valid XML, which would have a root element. If we assume there's no namespaces defined (there shouldn't be) then...

You can use the inner text of the element :

```
//td/span[@class='textinfo']/text()
```

I wouldn't put the `a` and `b` there - a "disabled" title wouldn't have the `a` for example. In either case using XPath to find the "title" isn't a very reliable approach

Comment: Whoops, I guess I assumed that I didn't need to include a root node since it didn't seem to be involved in the example.  I figured whatever solution would include some kind of //table/tbody as a root node for this example.  The application that I'm using uses xpath to find the URL and the title, I was just trying to simplify my example by just asking for the title.  I figured if I had that, I would be able to find the URL as well.  Why do you feel using Xpath to find the title isn't reliable?  Thanks for your input.

Comment: @rally_point because you have to rely on things that are not specifically designed for finding them, which means you could have an ad that has similar structure and responds to your XPath for example. If you have the option of modifying the HTML itself I'd include `class` attribute values